# How do I render a page with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've been trying to follow the structure of [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase/tree/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc) repo and from what I can see I've matched it and modified the required attributes.

When I run the project I get the error

`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!`

even though I only have one string matching `ContextLoader*` in my entire project, let alone my `web.xml`.

I have a lot of files where the error could lie so I won't include them all immediately for brevity, so if you think one may be pertinent please comment and I will add it but by and large they are similar to the repo linked earlier.. My project structure looks like this:

[image]

My `web.xml` looks like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Disables Servlet Container welcome file handling. Needed for compatibility with Servlet 3.0 and Tomcat 7.0 -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file></welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

How can I get it to load either the `index.html` or `home.jsp` page?

*edit*

`ApplicationConfig.java`

```
package brass.ducks;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ApplicationConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfig.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<ApplicationConfig> applicationClass = ApplicationConfig.class;



}
```

Comment: As a note, if you're new to Spring I recommend starting with Spring Boot, which makes all of this configuration unnecessary (and thus removes the potential for this error).

Comment: Can you remove the listener tag and try? It is not required since you are using DispatcherServlet.

Comment: As a note, if you're new to Spring and **want to learn how it works**, keep away from the spring boot magic.

Comment: Do you use any Abstract(Security)WebApplicationInitializer or other configuration class?

Comment: Pleas post your ApplicatioConfig class, it is likekly that this is the cause.

Comment: @Ralph added the `ApplicationConfig`

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing Spring-Boot and good old classic xml configuration in a way that does not work.

To get Boot, its configuration and way it works to run, delete the web.xml.

But what brothers me most is, that your configuration extends `SpringBootServletInitializer` (`SpringBootServletInitializer` is for [traditional deployment](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) (btw the class is [deprecated in Boot 1.4](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/web/SpringBootServletInitializer.html)))

Comment: I have deleted the `web.xml` and when I visit a URL that I want to render a page at it just returns the filename in string form.

Comment: But this also mean, that your application starts and is able to process web requests. - now google for "spring boot jsp" and flow for example this instructions https://hellokoding.com/spring-boot-hello-world-example-with-jsp/